# Which is a better measure of polarising power of a cation?

Tags: ions

Recently, I have come across literature stating that polarising power of a cation is proportional to the inverse of the surface area $(4\pi r^{2})$ while some associate it with the charge density of the cation, and thus state that it is proportional to the inverse of the volume $(\frac 43 \pi r^{3})$. I have been wondering which is a better measure of the polarising power. My knowledge of physics is limited so I would like to ask if anyone could kindly enlighten me on the matter.

Comment: I feel if you cite the literature (and relevant pages) as well, it would also  be of help to future readers of those particular textbooks :-)

Comment: Define "better".

Comment: @IvanNeretin "Better" would mean being able to give a more accurate approximation of the ion's polarising power.

Comment: Define "polarising power".

Comment: "Polarising power" would refer to the ability of a cation to distort the electron cloud of a neighbouring anion.